# How to uncheck another checkbox (which is defined after the main checkbox) if the main checkbox is unchecked

Tags: java, checkbox, wicket

I have two checkboxes like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new AjaxCheckBox("enableCheckBox1", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(channelModel, "checkBox1")) {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (!getModelObject()) {
           // How can I uncheck checkBox2 when checkBox1 is unchecked
           checkBox2.setModelObject(false); // compilation error as checkBox2 is defined after this line.
           target.add(checkBox2); // same compilation error
        }
    }
};

CheckBox checkBox2 = new AjaxCheckBox("enableCheckbox2", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(channelModel, "checkBox2")) {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (getModelObject()) {
           checkBox1.setModelObject(true);
           target.add(checkBox1);
        }
    }
};
```

When I check checkBox2, I would like checkBox1 to be auto checked, which I am able to do. But if I want to uncheck checkBox2 if checkBox1 is unchecked, how do I do that? I am encountering compilation error as checkBox2 is defined after the line using it. Is there another way to get the checkBox property other than calling the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to make those two checkboxes instance members of your components:

```
private CheckBox checkBox1;
private CheckBox checkBox2;

public YourComponent() {
  checkBox1 = ...;
  checkBox2 = ...;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you give me a bit more elaborated example?

Comment: You can this usage here:
https://github.com/Obee88/DeckBuilder/blob/master/src/main/java/obee/pages/ProfilePage.java

Comment: Thank you for the example but this does not work for me as this does not solve the problem for how I can do `checkBox2.setModelObject(false);` before initializing `checkBox2`?

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = null;
CheckBox checkBox2 = null;

checkBox1 = new AjaxCheckBox("enableCheckBox1", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(channelModel, "checkBox1")) {

  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    if (!getModelObject()) {
       // How can I uncheck checkBox2 when checkBox1 is unchecked
       checkBox2.setModelObject(false); // compilation error as checkBox2 is defined after this line.
       target.add(checkBox2); // same compilation error
    }
  }
};


checkBox2 = new AjaxCheckBox("enableCheckbox2", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(channelModel, "checkBox2")) {

  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    if (getModelObject()) {
       checkBox1.setModelObject(true);
       target.add(checkBox1);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This is not going to work as it will give compilation error in line `checkBox2.setModelObject(false);` as checkBox2 hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: I've made an edit, added `checkbox = null` to the first two lines. This should work!

Comment: Again, as the checkBox is not initialized, `checkBox2.setModelObject(false);` will still show compilation error.

Comment: No, it won't! `onUpdate()` is called much later than the initialization. Please create a demo application and share it at GitHub/BitBucket/...